# jqueryui tablesorter problem

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tablesorter

I am using the jQueryUI tablesorter component with about 200 rows.  I have the pages split into 20 rows each, and it seems to work great.  I recently added a jQueryUI button field to the first column of each row, and quickly found that the button effect isn't being applied to the rows above the initial 20.  Furthermore, the button doesn't fire any events, making me believe the effect isn't being applied to non-visible rows, or possibly something even worse.

It seems like I should be able to re-initialize the jQuery effects after pagination, but haven't found the magic potion.  A quick push in the right direction, or even some sample code would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!
Jim

Comment: Might it be that you failed to use the `.live()` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually overlooked one very important item... the order of the selectors.  My button/link code was placed after the tablesorter selector, so the links were only being applied to the visible rows.  A simply copy/paste to reorder the calls took care of it!

Answer (score 0):

You could place the initialization code in a function and run it again in the success callback of your pagination code.

Answer (score 0):

> he button effect isn't being applied to the rows above the initial 20. Furthermore, the button doesn't fire any events, making me believe the effect isn't being applied to non-visible rows, or possibly something even worse.

If the rows aren't being rendered at the browser, then the button can't possibly affect them.

Is it possible the button is doing something according to the row index instead of the record ID?